# Match string start with '[' using Glob pattern matching in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, glob

I have some data in JSON format like `[{"NewValue":"STATE"}]` and some are in plain text format like `NewValue is STATE"`. I want to filter out only JSON data using .NET Glob.parse() method.
I can do it with regular expression.

```
string pattern = @"^\[.*\]$";
string description = @"[{'NewValue':'STATE'}]";
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(description, pattern);
```

But I want to do something like this

```
GlobOptions GlobOptions = new GlobOptions
    {
        Evaluation = { CaseInsensitive = true }
    };
string pattern = @"^\[.*\]$";
var glob = Glob.Parse(pattern, GlobOptions);
string description = @"[{'NewValue':'STATE'}]";
var isMatch = glob.IsMatch(description, pattern);
```

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: thanks @Mikael. I have added my attempt

Comment: As a side hint, note that the construct `$"{string variable}"` can be simplified to just `variable`, as you don't have any extra characters in that string. So your call to Glob.Parse can be just `Glob.Parse(pattern, GlobOptions)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where I was forced to parse bad JSON

I used this method to process elements inside the array by making a special split option, here is my code

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits the specified string in the sections of open and closing characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The text.</param>
/// <param name="open">The opening char indicating where to start to read .</param>
/// <param name="close">The close char, indicating the part where should stop reading.</param>
/// <returns>IReadOnlyList&lt;System.String&gt;.</returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">text</exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Will throw an exception if the string that needs to be split is null or empty</exception>
public static IReadOnlyList<string> Split(this string text, char open, char close)
{
    if (text is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));
    }

    var counted = 0;
    var result = new List<string>();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (c == open)
        {
            if (counted != 0)
                sb.Append(c);

            counted++;
            continue;
        }
        if (c == close)
        {
            counted--;
            if (counted != 0)
                sb.Append(c);
            continue;
        }

        if (counted > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else if (counted == 0 && sb.Length > 0)
        {
            result.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
var jsonArray= description.Split(open: '[', close: ']');
```

I can then use my extension method to safely test if the JSON is valid

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the string contains valid JSON.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stringValue">The string value.</param>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if [is valid json] [the specified string value]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
public static bool IsValidJson(this string stringValue)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        return false;

    stringValue = stringValue.Trim();

    if (stringValue.Length == 0)
        return false;

    if ((stringValue.StartsWith("{") && stringValue.EndsWith("}")) //For object  
            ||
            (stringValue.StartsWith("[") && stringValue.EndsWith("]")) //For array
        )
    {
        try
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringValue);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```